# Argument out of range exception in CellEndEdit in data grid view

Tags: c#, asp.net, datagridview

I am beginner to ASP.NET and trying to study windows form, I am trying to create a simple student table on windows form where I will be able to Add, update and delete its details from the student table. I want to use stored procedure for delete and trigger for update. I have done the add part and it works fine. I dont have much idea on implementing trigger. Now I am trying to update and delete using CellEndEdit property as when I searched on net it seems to be the fastest way to edit and delete. I am now getting an Argument out of range exception. Can you please help to fix it and if possible also give me an idea to implement trigger. I have attached my form view and database structure along with the code so far which I have completed. Any help would be appreciated.

**Code for Class1.cs**

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Data;
using System.Data.SqlClient;

namespace WindowsFormsApplication1
{
    public class Class1
    {
    SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection();
    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand();

    public Class1()
    {
        con.ConnectionString = "server=.\\sqlexpress;database=sample;trusted_connection=true";
        cmd.Connection = con;
    }

    public void opencon()
    {
        if (con.State == ConnectionState.Open)
            con.Close();
        con.Open();
    }

    public SqlConnection getcon
    {
        get
        {
            return con;
        }
    }

    public SqlCommand getcmd
    {
        get
        {
            return cmd;
        }

    }

    public DataSet dataview()
    {
        //cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
        //cmd.CommandText = "select * from Student_table";
        SqlDataAdapter adp = new SqlDataAdapter("select * from Student_table",con);
        DataSet ds = new DataSet();
        //adp.SelectCommand = cmd;
        adp.Fill(ds, "Student_table");
        return ds;
    }
}
}
```

**Code for Form.cs**

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.Data.SqlClient;

namespace WindowsFormsApplication1
{
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    Class1 con = new Class1();
    DataGridView grid = new DataGridView();

    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        //grid.CellEndEdit += new DataGridViewCellEventHandler();
    }

    private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        this.student_tableTableAdapter.Fill(this.sampleDataSet.Student_table);
    }

    private void button4_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        con.opencon();
        lblstatus.Text = "Connected";

    }

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        con.opencon();
        con.getcmd.CommandText="insert into Student_table values('"+txtstname.Text+"','"+txtgrname.Text+"', '"+Convert.ToDateTime(dob.Value)+"','"+txtadd1.Text+"','"+txtadd2.Text+"')";
        con.getcmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
        //con.Close();
    }

    private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        con.opencon();
        con.getcmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
        con.getcmd.CommandText = "select * from Student_table";
        SqlDataAdapter adp = new SqlDataAdapter();
        DataSet ds = new DataSet();
        adp.SelectCommand = con.getcmd;
        adp.Fill(ds,"Student_table");
        ds = con.dataview();

        dataGridView1.DataSource = ds.Tables["Student_table"].DefaultView;
    }

    private void button3_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Application.Exit();
    }

    private void dataGridView1_CellContentClick(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
    {

    }

    private void btndel_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }

    private void dataGridView1_CellEndEdit(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
    {

        string query = string.Format(
        "UPDATE Student_table set {0}='{1}' WHERE id={2}",
        grid.Columns[e.ColumnIndex].Name, grid[e.ColumnIndex, e.RowIndex].Value,
        grid[0, e.RowIndex].Value); //**Argument out of range exception error here**

        try
        {
            con.getcmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
            con.getcmd.CommandText = query;
            con.opencon();
            con.getcmd.ExecuteNonQuery();

        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(ex.StackTrace);
        }
    }
}
```

}

**Please ignore the comments as I was experimenting different things to achieve my goal :)**
http://i50.tinypic.com/2yp0kl2.jpg

http://i47.tinypic.com/33az3lw.jpg

Comment: Hi, please trim down the amount of code you've posted here. Only post relevant code, not the entire program. Where exactly are you getting the ArgumentOutOfRange exception?

Comment: where do you get the error?

Comment: the error he's getting is on this line as depicted in his code `grid[0, e.RowIndex].Value)` Have you used the `Debugger` it appears that the Row that you are on may be correct but perhaps the column is not what if that were changed to `grid[1, e.RowIndex].Value)` something just doesn't look right

Comment: Thanks for your reply DJ Kraze, I've tried grid[1, e.RowIndex].Value) but the error still appears on that block of code. I tried debugger, the rowindex value seems to be correct but still getting error. **Index was out of range. Must be non-negative and less than the size of the collection.
Parameter name: index**